# Set max-length to structure fields in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, structure, maxlength

I´m working with Liferay 6.2 EE GA1 SP15 and I need something that allows me to set the max number of characters in text inputs of structures.
I found an app in Liferay marketplace but is for LF 6.1

Answer (score 1):

#### Bad News

The functionality to set a maximum character length for a text input of in a structure does not necessarily exist as a configuration in the Liferay 6.2 portal.  You are not the only person that wants this as there is currently an open feature request on the Liferay public JIRA page.

https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-53197

> **Note:** Even if added, this will likely only developed for Liferay 7 / DXP.

#### Good News

There is a bit of good news though.  The reason that marketplace plugin exists in 6.1 but not for 6.2 is because in 6.1 to modify a structure you need to create Java hook in order to create an Asset Display View.  If you download the LPKG file (that you linked to) from the Liferay marketplace and decompile it you can verify that what you are download/installing is actually just that (an asset display view hook).

However, in 6.2 you can write can your own Asset Display Template in FreeMaker code and then actually publish it without writing a Java hook to do this.  There is **several** very good tutorial that explains this on the Liferay blogs.

https://web.liferay.com/web/paulo.fernandes/blog/-/blogs/accessing-a-web-content-structure-from-application-display-template

https://web.liferay.com/pt/web/eduardo.garcia/blog/-/blogs/new-ways-of-customization-with-application-display-templates-part-i-

https://web.liferay.com/pt/web/eduardo.garcia/blog/-/blogs/new-ways-of-customization-with-application-display-templates-part-ii-

Comment: Where can I find the standard maximum lengths for each type?

Comment: @Michelle what do you mean “find the standard maximum lengths”?